# cURL not returning any value

Tags: php, curl, get

I'm new to the use of cURL but it is now central for a project I'm working on and I need a bit of help.

I have a page with a PHP script that will GET values passed via the cURL request in order to return a json string.

I then need to parse the json, in order to use the resulting value as a variable for a successive GET to a different page.

My code is the following:

```
$user_login = 'xxxxxx';
$user_id = 'xxxxxx';


// Define the URL where we will be sending a request for a random key
$api_url = "http://mywebsite.com/autologin-api/";

// Set the parameters
$params = array(
    'action'            => 'get_login_key',
    'key'               => $user_id,
    'user_login'       => $user_login
);

// Send the data using cURL
$ch = curl_init($api_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$gbi_response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

// Parse the response
parse_str($gbi_response);

// Convert the response to an array
$data = json_decode($gbi_response, true);

// Set the received key to a variable
$key = $data['key'];


echo "<a href='http://mywebsite.com/login/?key=" . $key . "'>Go and login</a>";
```

I know that the PHP script on the other side works fine, because if I go to the web address in my browser, passing the above parameter I can see the json response. Nevertheless the cURL always comes back empty.

I have looked online almost everywhere, trying different combinations/variations of cURL commands, always with no result.

Is anybody able to give me a hand?

Your time and help is very appreciated.

Comment: use `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1)` and inspect the server/PHP logs to see what the request and response look like on the wire

Comment: The code itself is fine - I have just run it on my server and it worked exactly as expected. Try `print_r($gbi_response)` to see what you're getting back.